# Save password for sheet protection

Tags: excel, excel-2007

One of my users is in charge of an Excel table which is also used by his subordinates. He want them to only be able to edit the first few columns. Editing other columns should be password protected.

I showed him how to lock/unlock cells and how to protect/unprotect the sheet, but he's not satisfied: If he unprotects it to edit something, it has to be protected again before closing (else it will be unprotected when opened the next time). But he doesn't want to enter the password every single time.

Is there a way to save the initially entered password?

Basically, he wants to only have to enter the password when unprotecting. Protecting the file should either happen with a single click or automatically when closing it.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690793/how-to-protect-excel-workbook-using-vba), add protection mode then if unprotected assign the password its been unprotected with to a variable then save at workbook_close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use VBA to automatically protect the workbook everytime it is saved by using the before saved event of the workbook like so:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  Thisworkbook.Protect("Password", true, false)
End Sub
```

Remember to also password project the VBA project code from being viewed otherwise the password will be visible to everyone.