# File saved from macro file as .xlsx extension but loses protection after save

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to save a workbook (.xlsx) with a password code so when users try to open it will prompt to enter the password. Or, otherwise will display an alert that the file is protected.

Users will be able to see all data but not to update/insert/delete.

```
Sub Macro2()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    ChDir "C:\Users\shane\Desktop"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\shane\Desktop\password.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    ChDir "C:\Users\shane\Desktop"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\shane\Desktop\password.xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub

Comment: Code goes in your question - please edit to include it.  Code in comments is too difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the VBA documentation ([https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx]) for the `Workbook.SaveAs` method.

The third optional parameter to that method is `Password`.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for coming up with options. I have had  a try on .save as and 'password'. It saves the file in protected mode and when you open, alert message shows up an user can't change cell contents(which is good). Soon, a user go to 'Review Tab' and pressing 'unprotect sheet' it simply unprotects it. Rather, a password should be prompted to unprotect it. Thanks..!

Comment: ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, Password:='123'

Answer (score 0):

Although you asked a while ago I did some research on this topic. I can confirm that using `ActiveSheet.Protect "yourPassword"` will protect your cells (unless locked property is set) **but** it will **not prompt an input box for the user to enter the password**.

I looked around and found some related/similar questions with the same topic. *eg. [How to protect Excel workbook using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690793/how-to-protect-excel-workbook-using-vba)* And the answer shown there, pops up the password box.

I tried around and found that using the **AllowFiltering** will trigger the password box. I am still searching around to find a reason for this behaviour.

*If anyone can find a link/post a hint - any info on this topic is very welcome!*

---

Finally this code works for me according to the asked questions/comments.

```
Sub ProtectCells()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    ChDir "C:\Users\shane\Desktop"

    ' WORKS
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="111", AllowFiltering:=True

    ' will NOT WORK!! (won't prompt a password box)
    'ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="111", AllowSorting:=True

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\shane\Desktop\password.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="222", CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```