# Unprotect not working in excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I've a macro which unprotect the sheet and do some calculation and protect the sheet after calculation.

```
Sheets("test").unProtect Password:="aaaa"

'calculation

Sheets("test").Protect Password:="aaaa", AllowFormattingcells:=true
```

It works fine in excel 2010, but in excel 2013 sheet is not unprotected and throws error.

I don't know what mistake I made? Please help me to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

Password should be given as given below, please try the below code..

```
Sheets("test").unProtect "aaaa"

Sheets("test").Protect "aaaa"
```

FYR [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690793/how-to-protect-excel-workbook-using-vba)

Comment: One More Question: 1) Is it possible to disable the picture selection without protecting the sheet ?

Comment: Is the above code is working? If yes please accept it as an answer (tick mark) and please ask the new question in an another post so that everyone will come to know..

Comment: what is the error message you get and on which line?

Comment: "The Password you supplied is not correct.Verfiy that the CAPS LOCK key is off and be sure to use the correct capitalization". Eventhough i've given the correct password.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following codes:

```
Sub sheetUnprotect()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Unprotect "aaaa"
End Sub
```