# Excel VBA - Create Another Excel File with Password Protected

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Excel Program that need to create another excel with password protected. I can create another excel but i don't know how to protect it with password. Below are the code for the creating another Excel File.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim Wk As Workbook

Set Wk = Workbooks.Add
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Wk.SaveAs Filename:=”B:\Test1.xlsx”
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Hope you guys can help for this part.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690793/how-to-protect-excel-workbook-using-vba

Comment: `Wk.password = "password"` or `Wk.protect "password"`, according to what you want to protect.

Comment: @VincentG thanks. i'm using **Wk.password = "password"** and it is working. however. when i run those code above, the newly created file is opened. How to suppress that?

Comment: @VincentG, its ok. found the way. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="pass", WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Here is the documentation: [Workbook.SaveAs Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx)