# Protecting a new excel sheet that has been exported

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have the following macro that exports a current excel sheet with some data to a new workbook into a specific path. The trouble i have, is that i want to protect that workbook new sheet after is created. How it can be done? I tried using `ActiveWorkbook.Protect "Password"` but did not worked.

```
Sub NuevoDia()
Dim FilePath As String
Dim NewName As String

FilePath = "C:\Users\Pol\Desktop\": NewName = FilePath & "Registros " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") & ".xls"

Sheets("Registros").Select
Hoja3.Unprotect "LOG2020"
Sheets("Registros").Copy

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewName, FileFormat _
:=xlWorkbookNormal, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you want to protect sheet or workbook ? In your issue content you try to protect workbook and in title you ask to protect sheet

Comment: You don't need to `.Select` the Registros sheet to copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To protect a sheet I would suggest to do :

```
Sheets("Registros").Protect "password"
```

And if you wanted to [protect workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3691503/11167163) since you tried :

```
ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="password", Structure:=True, Windows:=True
```

Also note that it is better to not use select so

```
Sheets("Registros").Select
Hoja3.Unprotect "LOG2020"
Sheets("Registros").Copy
```

do the same as

```
Hoja3.Unprotect "LOG2020"
Sheets("Registros").Copy
```

Comment: Thank you very much, was easier than i thought.

Comment: @Santiago glad that I could help you